# boto3 file upload in python

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

i am trying to upload file in aws s3 bucket via boto 3

but instead of file the following is being uploaded `<_io.TextIOWrapper name='excel.csv' mode='a' encoding='UTF-8'>`

```
def write_csv(data):
    with open('excel.csv', 'a') as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file)
        writer.writerow([data['account_id'],
                         data['country'],
                         data['end_date'],
                         data['start_date']])

    uploadtos3(str(file))


def uploadtos3(file):
    key = 'xxxx'
    seckey = 'xxxx'
    s3 = boto3.resource(  's3',
                           aws_access_key_id = key,
                           aws_secret_access_key = seckey)
    upload_file_bucket = 'apiuploadtest'
    s3.Object(upload_file_bucket,str(file)).put(Body = str(file))
```

how to upload the file correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Body` in the [put](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Object.put) method of `Object` is:

> Body (bytes or **seekable file-like object**) -- Object data.

Therefore, the following should be tried (fixed indentation and removed `str`):

```
def write_csv(data):
    with open('excel.csv', 'a') as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file)
        writer.writerow([data['account_id'],
                         data['country'],
                         data['end_date'],
                         data['start_date']])

        uploadtos3(file)


def uploadtos3(file):
    key = 'xxxx'
    seckey = 'xxxx'
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3',
                         aws_access_key_id = key,
                         aws_secret_access_key = seckey)
    upload_file_bucket = 'apiuploadtest'
    s3.Object(upload_file_bucket, <key-name-on-s3>).put(Body = file)
```

By the way, its **not a good practice to hardcode** any AWS credentials in your source code.

Comment: thanks mate it worked , but what if i want the <key-name-on-s3> same as the file name  and upload the file. and yes i just testing this code for an api call hence using aws key directly

Comment: @pyguru No problem. You can pass the file name as a second variable into `uploadtos3`.